# Database design, how to display dependency inside a table?

Tags: sql-server, database

My question title might be a little bit misleading, since I don't know how to word it. Sorry about that.

I have a table called `course` which holds a list of courses with `ID` and `Name` columns

```
ID   Name
---- ---------
1    JAVA
2    C#
3    C++
4    HTML
5    PHP
6    JAVASCRIPT
7    HARDWARE
8    PERL
9    CSS
```

There is a simple app, student ask if he can enroll a particular course, then the system will check he has finish the prerequisites. To do a particular course, you need to finish one or more prerequisites. Here are some silly examples:

- To do JAVA, you have to finish HARDWARE and HTML
- To do C++, you have to finish HARDWARE and PHP
- To do CSS, you have to finish JAVA

How can I show this relationship in database, do I need to add a new column to achieve this?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to introduce a second table called CoursePreRequiste. It could have the following columns:

`Id
CourseId
PreReqCourseId`

sample entries

```
Id  CourseId  PreReqCourseId
--- --------- --------------
1   1         4
2   1         7
```

The `CourseId` / `PreReqCourseId` combination has to be defined as unique in the table. You could of course do away with the Id column in the second column but I personally like to use Id in all my columns, it makes updating the table easier.

Comment: Thank you Raj, what do you mean by "You could ...the Id column in the second column"? Sorry about my English

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the dependency relationship in your table design. Per your description you have the following senarios:

- One Course can depend on many
- One Course can be a dependency for many

That is a many-to-many relationship, which is best expressed as an extra table containing a `Foreign key` to each of the relationship sides (in your case both are courses, from the same table). The new table design should be as Raj highlighted in his answer:

```
Id  CourseId  PreReqCourseId
--- --------- --------------
1   1         4
2   1         7
3   2         8
4   2         3
```

All you need later to know which courses a given course depends on is to run :

```
SELECT PreReqCourseId FROM ThisNewTable WHERE CourseId = @Value
```

Remember to change `@Value` with the Id of the course you are looking for or think about using it as a parameter if your script is called for an application (like C# or else)

Comment: is it possible that I create the new prerequisite table like this?    create table CoursePrerequisite
(
 CourseID int references Course (CourseID),
 Prerequisite int references Course(CourseID),
 Primary key (CourseID,Prerequisite)
)  thanks

Comment: Sorry about my poor format, I dont know how to format in the "add comment"